# regex: find all words with certain letters but not other

Tags: python, regex, letters

can anyone is help me with that:

I need to find all words from list containing letters [t OR d] AND [k OR c] but not any of [s,z,n,m]

I figured out first part, but don't know how to include stop list:

```
\w*[t|d]\w*[k|c]\w*
```

in Python notation

Thank you in advance

Comment: an example and your expected result would be helpful

Comment: `if (re.search('[td]', input) or re.search('[kc]', input)) and not re.search('[sznm]', input)`

Comment: Note that your current regex will only find words where `t` or `d` appears before `k` or `c` - is that what you want?

Comment: What do you mean by `[t OR d]`? Would `tried` be a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answer of [Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)

**EDIT** We both missed this condition

> [t OR d] AND [k OR c]

So - fixed accordingly

```
s = "detected dot knight track"

allowed = ({"t","d"},{"k","c"})
forbidden = {"s","z","n", "m"}

for word in s.split():
    letter_set = set(word)
    if all(letter_set & a for a in allowed) and letter_set - forbidden == letter_set:
        print(word)
```

And the result is

```
detected
track
```

Comment: Thank you, regex was not feasible idea in long run

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 steps. First find t|d AND k|c, then filter out matches with  unwanted letters.

Since you said you figured out first part, here is the second:

```
matches = [i for i in matches if not re.search(r'[sznm]', i)]    
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `t or d` appearing before `k or c`, use : `[^sznm\s\d]*[td][^sznm\s\d]*[kc][^sznm\s\d]*`.

`[^sznm\s\d]` means any character except `z, n, m, s`, whitespace characters (`\s`) or numbers (`\d`).

Comment: [^sznm] is not equal to **all letters except s, z, n, m** this is mean that word can containing signs spaces and ...

Comment: yep, thus the precision, but I added white space and numbers

Comment: ok, new suggested pattern is more acceptable but not excepted signs.

Comment: Your solution is working, but it made whole a bit complicated (it's just my issue), so I decided to avoid regex - thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "foobar foo".split()

allowed = ({"k", "c"}, {"r", "d"})
forbid = {"s","c","z","m"}

for word in s:
    if all(any(k in st for k in word) for st in allowed) and all(k not in forbid for k in word):
        print(word)
```

Or using a list comp with set.intersection:

```
words = [word for word in s if all(st.intersection(word) for st in allowed) and not denied.intersection(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import re
re.findall('[abcdefghijklopqrtuvwxy]*[td][abcdefghijklopqrtuvwxy]*[kc][abcdefghijklopqrtuvwxy]*', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer by @padraic-cunningham that does not make use of re, but here is a pattern, which will work:

```
pattern = r'(?!\w*[sznm])(?=\w*[td])(?=\w*[kc])\w*'
```

Positive `(?=...)` and negative `(?!...)` lookahead assertions are well documented on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookarounds.

```
^(?=.*[td])(?!.*[sznm])\w*[kc]\w*$
```

ie,

```
>>> l = ['fooktz', 'foocdm', 'foobar', 'kbard']
>>> [i for i in l if re.match(r'^(?=.*[td])(?!.*[sznm])\w*[kc]\w*$', i)]
['kbard']
```